# Timer inaccurate

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to implement a delay of 10 seconds before calling a a method. However, the method is being called in just one second.

```
 private void closeDoors(Floor floor)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 10000;
        timer.Tick += delegate 
        {
            DoorManager(floor, Operation.CLOSE, null);
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?
Thank you for your assistant.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong in this code snipped. There might be a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Are you using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`?

Comment: is it possible you have called `closeDoors` more than once creating multiple timers?

Comment: Your code is correct, so either closeDoors is being called more than once, or else DoorManager is being called from somewhere else in your code to make it look like the timer is firing.

Comment: Thanx guy. I am using the method more on four occassion where i am closing doors. Will try fix that.

Comment: also, you aren't tracking your timer.  For example, if you want to stop the timer elsewhere, you no longer have a reference to it outside of the `closeDoors` method.  You'll need to track the timer somehow to be able to stop it later (from somewhere outside of `DoorManager`, for example, if you are cleaning up before shutting down).  I assume `DoorManager` does something with the timer...

Comment: I have tried setting timer to global but not remedying the situation. I really have to implement closeDoors() four times for my door to close on every occasion.

Comment: DoorManager is not using the same timer. It has its own timer for a different event. Timer (timer) is mearnt to delay DoorManager() on four seperate occassions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may occur because of not stopping the Timer after finishing its job. The following modified code should work (as long as I've experienced with `Timer`):

```
private void closeDoors(Floor floor) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 10000;
    timer.Tick += (s,e) => {     
        DoorManager(floor, Operation.CLOSE, null);
        ((Timer)s).Stop();
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it by incrementing the timer Interval as the time delay was being utilised by a process invoked by another method call insideDoorManager().